# How to search for process by name with WinDBG

Tags: debuggers, windbg, process

I know how to list all the processes in the system by running:

```
0: kd>dx -r1 Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes  

OR
0: kd>.tlist
```

But how can I search for a process by name?
I tried to use the `Contains` function but it didn't work:

```
0: kd> dx -r1 Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes.Contains("chrome.exe")
Error: Cannot compare non-intrinsic values to each other.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
dx @$cursession.Processes.Where(p => p.Environment.EnvironmentBlock.ProcessParameters->CommandLine->ToDisplayString().Contains("chrome"))
```

If you have other way, please share.

Answer (score 1):

You Cannot use contains for objects they are not strings
contains only is meaningful when you have a partial case Sensitive pattern

here is how you may use contains

```
0: kd> dx Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.Where(p=>p.Name.Contains("Taskm"))
Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.Where(p=>p.Name.Contains("Taskm"))
    [0x2c14]         : Taskmgr.exe
```

or if you have a proper complete case sensitive pattern you can simply use == on the Process name

```
0: kd> dx Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.Where(p=>p.Name  == "Taskmgr.exe")
Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.Where(p=>p.Name  == "Taskmgr.exe")
    [0x2c14]         : Taskmgr.exe
0: kd> dx Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.Where(p=>p.Name  == "tAskmgr.exe")
Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.Where(p=>p.Name  == "tAskmgr.exe")
0: kd>
```